# create any algoritmy from text fragments (chunks)

Tags: python, text-mining

I have a final job of the text mining module, and I am in difficulties to solve the problem proposed, so I requested a support to follow up the work in python:

The objective is to program a function that receives as input a user text and returns the text fragments (chunks) that refer to the meals and quantities that you have requested. It is not necessary, nor is it the objective of this exercise, to build a classifier of intention prior to this function, but simply a function that we presuppose receives a phrase with the intention 'Order_food'. Nor is it objective to normalize the output (eg, it is not necessary to convert 'three' to '3' or 'pizzas' to 'pizza'). It is, therefore, an exercise of minimums.

Por ejemplo: “quiero 3 bocadillos de anchoas y 2 pizzas” →

```
 {comida:'bocadillo', ingrediente:'anchoas', cantidad:3},
 {comida:'pizza', ingrediente:'null', cantidad:2}
```

Therefore, the output of the function will be an array with dictionaries of 2 elements (food and quantity). When an amount is not detected, its value will be set to '1' as the default value.

best regards.

Answer (score 0):

In python i would use [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/) library to first classify the sentence.

For example:

1. please give me 2 sandwiches and a pizzas

   will give tagged result as

please/NN give/VBP me/PRP 2/CD sandwiches/NNS and/CC a/DT pizzas/NN

2. please give me three sandwiches and pizzas

please/NN give/VBP me/PRP three/CD sandwiches/NNS and/CC pizzas/NNS

Using tag i will clean the statement. (Keeping /CD, /DT, /NN and /NNS)

1. please/NN 2/CD sandwiches/NNS a/DT pizzas/NN
2. please/NN three/CD sandwiches/NNS pizzas/NNS

find first occurrence of /CD and if not first /DT and if not first /NN .. remove every from leading from it

1. 2/CD sandwiches/NNS a/DT pizzas/NN
2. three/CD sandwiches/NNS pizzas/NNS

consider /DT as 1 and also if there is no /CD and /DT between /NN and /NNS then i would consider 1 between them

final result is below which you parse in the format you need.

1. 2, sandwiches, 1, pizzas
2. three, sandwiches, 1, pizzas

This is just an example which will give you a start there are many flaws like multiple occurance of /NN or /NNS based on string you passing. also language in which string is passed.

But i hope community can extend and give better logic of categorising the statement once its tagged.

**You can clean the data by navigating in array. Below is example:**

```
mySentance = [('please', 'VB'), ('give', 'VB'), ('me', 'PRP'), ('2', 'CD'), ('sandwiches', 'NNS'), ('and', 'CC'), ('a', 'DT'), ('pizzas', 'NN')]
newData = ""
StartCapture = "No"

for i in range(len(mySentance)):
    if mySentance[i][1] == "CD" or mySentance[i][1] == "DT":
        StartCapture = "Yes"

    if StartCapture == "Yes":

        if mySentance[i][1] == "CD":
            newData = newData + mySentance[i][0] + " "

        if mySentance[i][1] == "DT":    
            newData = newData + "1 "

        if mySentance[i][1] == "NN":
            newData = newData + mySentance[i][0] + " "

        if mySentance[i][1] == "NNS":    
            newData = newData + mySentance[i][0] + " "
print(newData)
```

Result:
2 sandwiches 1 pizzas

Comment: [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) strongly recommends only answering well-asked questions